# WIX Custom Action to Launch an Elevated App

Tags: wix, installation, uac

This is my first crack at writing MSI installer. There's numerous posts here and elsewhere for custom commands in a WIX installer regarding UAC. Haven't found any that solve my issue, however.

I need to launch an app elevated in my MSI. I'm attempting to launch a .NET app (compiled to run as Admin) that will install a device driver. I use the .NET exe to display a 'connect device' prompt to the user if needed, then perform the actual driver install in unmanaged code.

The MSI immediately causes a UAC prompt, but the app then launches without elevation, and fails. Running from an elevated command prompt doesn't help. I read somewhere that adding the manifest to the install may help... it doesn't.

Here's my WIX code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
   <Product Id="*" UpgradeCode="12345678-1234-1234-1234-111111111111" 
            Name="FlashBoot Driver" Version="0.0.1" Manufacturer="ACME Corp" Language="1033">
      <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" Comments="Windows Installer Package"/>
      <Media Id="1" Cabinet="product.cab" EmbedCab="yes"/>

      <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
         <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
            <Directory Id="INSTALLDIR" Name="FlashBoot Driver">
               <Component Id="AppFiles" Guid="12345678-1234-1234-1234-222222222222">
                  <File Id="AppFile1" Source="C:\App\Release\Setup.exe"/>
                  <File Id="AppFile2" Source="C:\App\Release\Setup.exe.manifest"/>
                  <File Id="AppFile3" Source="C:\App\Release\Unmanaged.dll"/>
               </Component>
            </Directory>
         </Directory>
      </Directory>

      <Feature Id="DefaultFeature" Level="1">
         <ComponentRef Id="AppFiles"/>
      </Feature>

      <CustomAction Id="OurAction" 
                    Execute="deferred" 
                    Impersonate="no" 
                    Return="ignore" 
                    FileKey="AppFile1" 
                    ExeCommand="" />

      <InstallExecuteSequence>
         <Custom Action="OurAction" Before="InstallFinalize" />
      </InstallExecuteSequence>

   </Product>
</Wix>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by having the WIX installer launch a satellite app, which in turn launches the driver installer. The new app does not require elevation, while the driver installer does require elevation. An added benefit is that the new app can determine if it needs to run the 32 or 64bit version of the driver installer.

It still would be nice to know if there's a way to launch an app requiring elevation directly from the WIX installer though.

Comment: you need to configure the custom action to run deferred with no impersonation, this will make it run with admin privileges under the LocalSystem account. Also, the custom action must be sequenced after InstallFiles standard action, to make sure all your resources are on the machine when your try to install/use them. This method applies for custom actions from any MSI package, no matter the tool used to build it.

Comment: @Bogdon Mitrache, thanks for your reply. I thought I was doing what you suggest. As you can see, execution is deferred and impersonation is turned off. As for being sequenced after InstallFiles, doesn't "before InstallFinalize" accomplish the same thing?

Comment: hmm, sorry I must have missed your snippet, indeed your custom action is configured and scheduled correctly. What does the installation log say? Also, if you look with Process Explorer on the process of your custom action EXE, under which account it is started? Maybe your EXE needs to run under the current admin user, so even if it runs under the System account with admin privileges it will fail.

Comment: You're right, the EXE is running under the System account. I still don't understand why it won't run elevated if it's launched as System. My EXE includes a manifest with 'requireAdministrator' privileges.

Comment: Well if it is running under System account it is elevated, this is why don't see any UAC prompt. I think the problem is that the EXE is not designed to work under System account, maybe it needs to run directly under the current administrator user? I think you will need to attach and debug your custom action.